# Printing with loops in sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hi I wrote a procedure to accomplish a task and it looks like this

```
create or replace procedure myproc 
is
begin
  for rec_ in (
    select
      case 
        when highest_ = 1 then 
          'Most profit in ' || category || ' -> ' || carname || ': ' || aprofit
        when lowest_ = 1 then 
          'Least profit in ' || category || ' -> ' || carname || ': ' || aprofit
      end report
    from (
      select 
        category
      , carname
      , aprofit
      , rank() over ( partition by category order by aprofit asc ) lowest_
      , rank() over ( partition by category order by aprofit desc ) highest_
      from (
        select unique
          C.category
        , C.carname
        , avg( R.rentalrate - C.suggesteddealerrentalprice ) 
          over ( partition by C.category, C.carname ) as aprofit
        from rentals R 
          join car C on R.carid = C.carid 
          join cardealers CD on CD.dealerid = C.dealerid
        where CD.state = 'IN'
      )
    ) 
    where lowest_ = 1 or highest_ = 1 
    order by case when lowest_ > 1 then 2 else 1 end, category, carname
  )
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line( rec_.report ) ;
  end loop ;
end ;
/
begin 
  myproc ;
end ;
/
```

This prints out the output that looks like this

```
Least profit in compact -> Nissan Versa: 4
Least profit in compact -> Toyota Yaris: 4
Least profit in luxury -> Porsche: 40
Least profit in van -> Chrysler: 2
Most profit in compact -> Chevy Spark: 5
Most profit in luxury -> Audi: 45
Most profit in van -> Honda Odyssey: 9
```

I want it to print out like this that if a car category has more than one car inside it it only prints the heading one time. But as you can see in my output the heading for "Least profit in compact" is being printed two times. I want an output that looks like this

```
Least Profit in compact
- Nissan Versa: 4
- Toyota Yaris: 4
Least Profit in luxury
- Porsche: 40
Least Profit in van 
- Chrysler: 2
Most Profit in compact
- Chevy Spark: 5
Most Profit in luxury
- Audi: 45
Most Profit in van 
- Honda Odyssey: 9
```

The tables and data files are
[Data file](https://ufile.io/a6axi)
[Tables file](https://ufile.io/jn5mh)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may select the columns `Least/Most,category,carname,aprofit` separately from your select query and then use `DBMS_OUTPUT` conditionally.

I have used your sample dataset from the output in the below code as I do not have your table/ definitions.

```
DECLARE
 v_high_low VARCHAR2(40) := 'DUMMY';
 v_category VARCHAR2(40) := 'DUMMY';
BEGIN
for rec_ IN
 (
with t (high_low,category,carname,aprofit) AS
  (
   select 'Least profit in ','compact', 'Nissan Versa', 4    from dual union all
   select 'Least profit in ','compact','Toyota Yaris',  4    from dual union all
   select 'Least profit in ','luxury','Porsche',        40   from dual union all
   select 'Least profit in ','van','Chrysler',          2    from dual union all
   select 'Most profit in ','compact','Chevy Spark',    5    from dual union all
   select 'Most profit in ','luxury','Audi',            45   from dual union all
   select 'Most profit in ','van', 'Honda Odyssey',     9    from dual 
   )
 SELECT * FROM t order by high_low,category,carname
  ) 
  LOOP
        IF rec_.high_low  != v_high_low OR rec_.category != v_category
         THEN
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(rec_.high_low);
           v_high_low := rec_.high_low;
         END IF;
        IF rec_.category != v_category 
          THEN
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rec_.category);
          v_category := rec_.category;
        END IF;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' - '||rec_.carname||': '|| rec_.aprofit);

   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=52bae03c944b9ac00b51f9f245cc6971)

**EDIT** - Adding this demo link with the procedure with actual tables provided :
[**DEMO2**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c19f44236e55f9f3103ac4b0e8693772)

Comment: Hi @Kaushik thanks for the reply. I have added the tables and data to the original question. Can you pls edit your answer using those?

Comment: @rshtate : Please check my Edits, the modified procedure is available in the 2nd demo link